# JavaFX TableView setando valores a TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx

Acabei encontrando um problema que acredito que seja trivial mas não sei como solucionar. Tenho uma classe `Seller` que tem uma associação com outra classe: `Department`. E eu preciso de uma TableView que popule duas colunas com os dados do banco de dados, sendo a primeira `@FXML private TableColumn<Seller, String> sellerName` e a segunda `@FXML private TableColumn<Seller, String> departmentName` e a `Table view`: `@FXML private TableView<Seller> tableViewSeller`.

A primeira coluna deve ser responsável por listar o nome de todos os vendedores (Seller) e a segunda coluna seus respectivos departamentos (Department), de forma associada. O problema está na hora de passar o que ele deve colocar na coluna do nome do departamento, sendo que na classe `Seller`ela possui uma associação com `Department` e o seu construtor recebe um `new Department("Exemplo");`para instanciar um `Seller`. Para acessar por exemplo, o nome do departamento deve-se fazer `Seller seller = new Seller(); seller.getDepartment().getName;`. De que maneira eu consigo popular a segunda coluna com o respectivo departamento de um vendedor sendo que não há nada que se possa passar aqui `departmentName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("*****"));` que referencie um atributo de uma associação ?

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que a estrutura da sua classe Seller é a seguinte:

```
public class Seller {

    private String sellerName;
    private Departamento department;

    public Seller(...) {
        department = new Department("Exemplo");
    }
}
```

Você tem as seguintes opções:

**1:** Construir um método toString na classe Department utilizando somente o nome do departamento.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome;
}

@FXML private TableColumn<Seller, Department> department;
department.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("department"));
```

**2:** Utilizar o cell factory (Normalmente se usa quando queremos formatar as células da tabela, utilizando datas por exemplo)

```
@FXML private TableColumn<Seller, Department> department;
department.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("department"));
department.setCellFactory(coluna -> {
    return new TableCell<Seller, Department>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Department item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(item != null && !empty) {
                setText(item.getName());
            } else {
                setText("");
            }
        }
    };
 });
```